# Large finite permutation group

Tags: finite-groups

I have a transitive permutation group G of degree 26688 of a group G with four generators. I would like to know the order of the permutation group. I have tried constructing the group and doing FactoredOrder(G), but after 4 weeks my computer crashed (doing something else unrelated). Is there a better way to find the order of G?

Comment: I was using Magma to do the computations.

Comment: How do you "have" the group? i.e. in what way is it defined?

Comment: You'll need to give more information about the specific group if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: I have four generators p1,p2,p3,p4 as elements of Sym(26688). Three of them <p2,p3,p4> generate a group of order 48. The element p1 p2 has order 1312486560.